# React Material UI: accordion horizontal expansion

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to change the direction of the expansion of the React Material UI Accordion?

https://mui.com/components/accordion/#customization

I don't see anything in the docs concerning the `direction` of the expansion.